# What is "Standard Test and Programming Language" (STAPL) and is it worth learning it?

Tags: fpga, jtag

I can see that the Standard Test and Programming Language is related to JTAG in some way, but is it something universal? I have not found any book on this language so far which is quite strange.

What can one do with STAPL?

Comment: Check WIKI....yet?

Comment: Wiki says nothing bad about it.  So I might try with my STM32 board.

Comment: wiki is basically not answering all of my questions, I want to know what I can do with FPGAs using this language

Comment: I think Altera support it. If you need to use it, it's probably worth learning. If you don't ... probably not.

Comment: I do need to use it, I can see that even Microsemi programming tools generate STAPL code. I need to write a STAPL script to make the Microsemi programmer communicate with device logic through the virtual JTAG IP basically.

Comment: I think STAPL is the only way to control a JTAG programmer in an arbitrary way so we can make the FPGA JTAG controller do user defined functions. I am not sure of any other way with this at all.